# Removing all properties and personal information from a file automatically

Tags: windows-7, file-management, properties

When I share files online, I find myself doing the `Properties`/`Detail`/`Remove all properties and personal information` by hand in Explorer each time.  The result of this is that a copy of the file with the same name is made, and `-Copy` is appended onto the file name.

I'm wondering if at a minimum there's a way to do this operation "in place" and not end up with a copy of the file (which clutters up the directories quickly).  In other words, a click in Explorer processes the file and leaves it where it was, sans the information.  A method that makes a copy and deletes the original would work, too.

If I can be optimistic, and there is such a method to do the above, is there some sort of extension that I could integrate with my save dialog in, say, MS Paint to make this removal of personal information extraction part of the saving process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen no answer so I give you my solution:

- display the developer menu to be able to record a macro.
- record a macro while saving your file and give it a short key for automatic saving
- record a macro while purging you file from hidden informations (see here below for the method)

Combine both code for purging hidden data before saving.

For purging files from hidden data, look on internet according to your Office version. As an example "[remove hidden data from word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-from-office-documents-HA010037593.aspx)".

Resulting code in the macro looks like: ActiveDocument.RemoveDocumentInformation (wdRDIRevisions)
when only removal of revision information is performed.
Take care that removal of Metadata can result in document formating changes (I experimented a change from 48 to 81 pages in a word document to be sent to a client). I don't know why this happened but its not nice.
For the other purging options such as for headers and footers, you have to be carfull on unexpected formting changes as well.

This can be apply to Word, Excel and Power Point files.